# Do <span> elements with "position: absolute;" behave as block-level elements?

Tags: css, block, html, absolute

Are `<span>` elements with `position: absolute;` able to have a height, width, padding, etc. without changing it to `display: block;` or `inline-block;`?

It seems to work, but is it ok with all browsers to omit `display: block/inline-block` for a `<span>` element with `position: absolute;`?

Comment: why would you not use a < div > instead of a < span > if you are planning on setting the height, width and padding?

Answer (score 5):

The spec [says yes](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo):

> Otherwise, if 'position' has the value 'absolute' or 'fixed', the box is absolutely positioned, the computed value of 'float' is 'none', and display is set according to the table below. The position of the box will be determined by the 'top', 'right', 'bottom' and 'left' properties and the box's containing block.

The table says that any inline `display` values (inline, table-row-group, table-column, table-column-group, table-header-group, table-footer-group, table-row, table-cell, table-caption, inline-block) become `block`.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: yes.

Long answer: see http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo (or SLaks's answer).

Hovewer, this change refers only to the visual display model of the element. The CSS can't affect the [content model](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#content-models) of the HTML element since CSS is applied only after the document is parsed into DOM tree. So `span` element can never have `p` or `div` children, no matter which styles are applied to it.