# Percent is not working in css

Tags: css

I am not able to set div height in %. But its working in px;

```
html, body {
 height: 100%;
}

.parent {
    position: absolute;
}

.child {
 height: 300px;   <<--- Want this to be in %
    overflow: auto;
    position: absolute;
}

.childsChild {
   height: 100%;
   position: relative;
}
```

my html structure is

```
Div -> Parent
  Div -> Child
    Div -> childsChild
```

Whenever i try to do it with % its not taking. Can anyone help me to fix this issue ?

Comment: Can you share your html code that's causing the problem?

Comment: The parent has no height.... So the child when using `%` will be 0. Also you would need a width.. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/vfXwL/)

Comment: I Tried to add height to parent but its not taking in both % & px!

Comment: @iCybernetics Look at my demo.

Comment: because you have `absolute` positioning and the parent does not even have a declared `height`. So child can't calculate the percentage value. Also, things wont show up till you give the `absolute`ly positioned elements a `width` or put some content within them.. - http://jsfiddle.net/eLfez/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right so in your code you have a parent `div` with no height. In the parent you have a child with`height: 30%`. How can the child be `width: 30%` and show in? `30%` of 0  is... 0.

Also you should define a width for them (because you have them `position: absolute;`), more on this [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15763027/absolute-position-affects-width).

### HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        <div class="childsChild"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.parent {
    position: absolute;
    background: red;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.child {
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    position: absolute;
    background: blue;
}
.childsChild {
    height: 30%;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background: green;
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/vfXwL/1/)

Comment: mention, width is also important here since the elements are absolutely positioned. or until they have some content in them.

Answer (score -1):

Since the **.child** css class contains **absolute positioning** it doesn't understand how much is height in **%**.

You will have to provide a fixed height in this case.

% works when the positioning is not absolute or your container itself is contained inside another container which might be absolute but has some value that too is fixed i.e. 300px or somthing

Comment: This is incorrect. [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/fBzfj/). Absolute position elements can have a `% ` height as long as there parent has a defined width. Take a look at my demo.

Comment: Ruddy, This is the same i mentioned "% works when the positioning is not absolute or your container itself is contained inside another container which might be absolute but has some fixed value for height"

Comment: Not following you, it don't matter what is absolute positioned. It will work, as long as the absolute position element has a parent.

Comment: Ruddy, But the parent must have defined values. That's what I said.

Comment: I cant be asked to read this all again. Just put it this way, the way you have worded it (maybe) was not very good. If it confused me it probably would confuse other people. You don't have an up-vote on this so I guess no one else found it very useful. Take a look at my answer, its displays code and gives an example. This is as much better way to create an answer and easier to follow. Try to take note from it and I'm sure the next answer you create will get some upvotes.

Comment: I'm no hurry to earn up-votes and certainly not jealous of yours. But I know now that the answer needs to be thorough and elaborate. Cheers!!!

Answer (score -1):

Put the percent like this:

```
height:100vh;
```

Comment: No.. This is not how it should be done. Read more about `vh`[**here**](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/vm-vh-units)