# Why is the absolute positioned DIV not inheriting the width of parent?

Tags: html, css

Why is the absolute positioned DIV not inheriting the width of its parent? Div has

```
div {
  position: absolute;
  top:100px;
}

<html>
<body>
  <div>This DIV</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In static positioning the DIV takes all available space, in absolute the width of the DIV is as long as the length of its contents.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS_absolute_and_fixed_positioning#Specifying_dimensions

Comment: Danip I read the link, my div ancestor is html which is full screen so why width:inherit in my div css does not work?  Please explain.

Answer (score 4):

The default width of a div is auto. It is automatically the width of the content inside. It does not inherit the width from the parent. To do this you need to specify inherit on the width of the div

```
div {
    position: absolute;
    top:100px;
    width: inherit;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BLPNrm

Comment: did not work, div width still the width of contents.

Comment: You need to set the width of the body and it will inherit... or wrap the div in another div and set the width of that. The body's default width is auto too.

Comment: I'm using the html as the parent that's is full width. Width of body is 100% right now as well.

Comment: body is the parent because it is the tag before your div.

Answer (score 4):

> Because absolutely positioned elements do not behave as block level elements and do not flow after each other like normal a div does.

[absolute position affects width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15763027/absolute-position-affects-width)

Comment: Came to say this. If you want the div to be the width of it's parent. set the parent position to relative and the absolute element to width: 100%;

Comment: @JamesHamann but obvs does not work if the width of the parent is implicit (i.e. determined by the size of the text or the padding or whatever

Answer (score 3):

Read @DaniP docs link for the answer.

Add style width : inherit for inheriting the width of its parent

```css
#divParent{
  width:300px;
}


#divAbsolute {
  position: absolute;
  top:100px;
  background:red;
  width:inherit;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div id="divParent">
    <div id="divAbsolute">This DIV</div>
  </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this does not inherit from parent, you're assuming parent's width is 100%;