# Footer content could not set up exact center?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have tried to set up the bootstrap footer content at the center of the bottom. But unfortunately footer did not set up exactly center position . I have not figured out the errors. Please help me.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<footer class="container text-center"; style="position:absolute; bottom:0px; ">
 <p>This is my footer content</p>  
</footer>
```

Comment: you should add width:100% .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this code

**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
   <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
     <footer class="container text-center"; style="position:absolute; bottom:0px; width:100%; ">
       <p>This is my footer content</p>  
     </footer>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: why I add width:100%? Please explain it.

Comment: always html width generated auto. so we set width 100%

Answer (score 1):

> Add This, if you don't want use width:100%; use left:0px; and right:0px;

```css
 footer{
        position:absolute;
        bottom:0px;
        text-align:center;
        width:100% !important; /** Because of your are using position for center text so width are necessary positioning **/
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
   <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
     <footer class="container">
       <p>This is my footer content</p>  
     </footer>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to aplly **`width:100%`** to the container like @Ranjith solution, but for understanding it:

By default, when you apply **`position: absolute`** to an element, it's width become the width of it's content. You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15763027/absolute-position-affects-width). That make it can not align the text content since there is no space left in the element

And it important to know that Bootstrap **`container`** class [have a fixed width](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints) on each responsive breakpoints. So the text is aligned but based on the **`container`** class defined width.

So apply **`width:100%`** make the **`<footer>`** expand to the rear of it container(in this case is the **`<body>`** element), then it have enough space for the text to be aligned.